# Modelo ARIMA com lag em 1 e 25 no R

Tags: r

Por favor, ao aplicar a modelagem ARIMA(p,d,q) em uma série , na função de autocorrelação parcial aparece um pico em lag 1 e outro em 25 e nenhum outro estatisticamente significativo. 
Existe algum comando no R para tratar desses dois lags apenas, sem incluir 25 coeficientes regressivos?

Comment: Henrique, tu chegou a ver se não é um comportamento sazonal? Se o lag 50 também não é significativo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim existe.

Considerando a série `lh` do R:

```
> lh
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 48 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.2 2.1 1.5 2.3 2.3 2.5 2.0 1.9 1.7 2.2 1.8 3.2 3.2 2.7 2.2 2.2 1.9 1.9
[22] 1.8 2.7 3.0 2.3 2.0 2.0 2.9 2.9 2.7 2.7 2.3 2.6 2.4 1.8 1.7 1.5 1.4 2.1 3.3 3.5 3.5
[43] 3.1 2.6 2.1 3.4 3.0 2.9
```

Ajuste o modelo assim:

```
> arima(lh, order = c(1,1,1), fixed = c(NA, 0))

Call:
arima(x = lh, order = c(1, 1, 1), fixed = c(NA, 0))

Coefficients:
          ar1  ma1
      -0.0404    0
s.e.   0.1443    0

sigma^2 estimated as 0.2525:  log likelihood = -34.35,  aic = 72.7
```

Neste caso, estou dizendo que o parâmetro AR1 é livre (estimado pelo modelo) e que o MA1 é igual a zero por meio do argumento `fixed`.

No seu caso, se você quisesse ajustar um `arima(25,1,0)` com apenas os coeficientes 1 e 25 do AR, poderia fazer assim:

```
> arima(lh, order = c(25,1,0), fixed = c(NA, rep(0,23), NA))

Call:
arima(x = lh, order = c(25, 1, 0), fixed = c(NA, rep(0, 23), NA))

Coefficients:
          ar1  ar2  ar3  ar4  ar5  ar6  ar7  ar8  ar9  ar10  ar11  ar12  ar13  ar14
      -0.0539    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
s.e.   0.1343    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
      ar15  ar16  ar17  ar18  ar19  ar20  ar21  ar22  ar23  ar24    ar25
         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  0.2994
s.e.     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  0.1918

sigma^2 estimated as 0.2297:  log likelihood = -33.3,  aic = 72.6
```

O argumento `fixed` é sempre um vetor com o número de elementos igual ao número de parâmetros que o seu modelo possui. Você pode pré-especificar qualquer valor para os parâmetros, mas normalmente usamos apenas 0 (quando não queremos aquele termo) e NA (quando queremos que o parâmetros seja estimado pelo modelo).

Comment: Veja se isso funciona: `arima(lh, order = c(25,1,1), fixed = c(rep(0,24), NA, NA))`